# MSSQL RowNumber wrong row number over DateTime which is generated from string

Tags: sql-server, datetime, row-number

I'm using the below sql query and I get unexpected results. It is as if the sql is making a row number over string not over DateTime even though I have casted the generated sstring to DateTime. Can you help me align the indecies correctly?
Thank you.

**THE SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ((SELECT CAST(CAST(emd.DateOfMeasure AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + 
                ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, DateOfMeasure) AS NVARCHAR) +
                ':' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, DateOfMeasure) AS NVARCHAR) + ':00' AS DATETIME))) AS RowNum, 
CAST((SELECT CAST(CAST(emd.DateOfMeasure AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + 
                ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, DateOfMeasure) AS NVARCHAR) +
                ':' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, DateOfMeasure) AS NVARCHAR) + ':00' AS DATETIME) AS DATETIME) AS 'Date'
            from Data emd
```

**THE UNEXPECTED RESULT**

```
Index      DateTime
1   2013-10-16 00:30:00.000
2   2013-10-16 00:45:00.000
3   2013-10-16 01:00:00.000
4   2013-10-16 01:15:00.000
5   2013-10-16 01:30:00.000
6   2013-10-16 01:45:00.000
7   2013-10-16 10:00:00.000
8   2013-10-16 10:15:00.000
    .
    .
    .
45  2013-10-16 19:30:00.000
46  2013-10-16 19:45:00.000
47  2013-10-16 02:00:00.000
48  2013-10-16 02:15:00.000
```

Comment: `DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,GETDATE()),0)` returns the current date and time with the seconds truncated to 0, and moreover continues to treat it as a `datetime` rather than a string. Is that what you're trying to do with that ugly string manipulation?

Comment: No, I have grouped by Date, hour and minute. But maybe I can group by your suggestion

Comment: Also you might as well just do row_number over the non truncated time if the above comment is correct. Rows in the same minute will get an arbitrary ascending number so no reason why this can't be the actual time order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, I think that this is a simpler formulation of your query:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,DateOfMeasure),0)) AS RowNum, 
DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,DateOfMeasure),0) AS 'Date'
from Data emd
```

Does it also exhibit the same strangeness?